# Handling array of stateful objects in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have array of stateful objects (where either size of array or attributes of objects can change). My original plan was having a textfields where user can change course attributes but when i started implementing code. I noticed function **changeCourseAttribute** and overall code, was becoming more complicated than it should be so my question is there way to handling this, more elegantly ?

Because with my current implementation. For example if i had **< CourseComponent />** i would have to call **changeCourseAttribute** pass all arguments it needs and on top of that it would also call re-render on all components which is unnecesarry.

I would be greatful if anyone could help thanks.

```js
import { React, useState } from "react";

class Semester {
  constructor(courses = []) {
    this.courses = courses;
  }
}

class Course {
  constructor(name = "", credits = "", grade = "") {
    this.name = name;
    this.credits = credits;
    this.grade = grade;
  }
}

const App = () => {
  const [semesters, setSemesters] = useState([new Semester()]);

  function addSemester() {
    setSemesters([...semesters, new Semester()]);
  }

  function removeSemester(semesterToBeRemoved) {
    if (semesters.length > 1) {
      setSemesters(
        semesters.filter((semester) => semesterToBeRemoved !== semester)
      );
    }
  }

  function addCourse(semesterToBeChanged) {
    setSemesters(
      semesters.map((semester) =>
        semester === semesterToBeChanged
          ? { ...semester, courses: [...semester.courses, new Course()] }
          : semester
      )
    );
  }

  function removeCourse(semesterToBeChanged, courseToBeRemoved) {
    if (semesterToBeChanged.courses.length > 1) {
      setSemesters(
        semesters.map((semester) =>
          semester === semesterToBeChanged
            ? {
                ...semester,
                courses: semester.courses.filter(
                  (course) => course !== courseToBeRemoved
                ),
              }
            : semester
        )
      );
    }
  }

  function changeCourseAttribute(
    semesterToBeChanged,
    courseToBeChanged,
    field,
    data
  ) {
    // This is just insanity..
  }

  return <div>{/* Rest of the code .. */}</div>;
};

export default App;
```